# Bookings system

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

This is the database schema:

```
   CREATE TABLE `bookings` (
      `id` int(2) NOT NULL,
      `start` time NOT NULL,
      `end` time NOT NULL
    )

    INSERT INTO `bookings` VALUES(1, '13:00:00', '14:30:00');
    INSERT INTO `bookings` VALUES(2, '15:00:00', '16:00:00');
```

I tried to run the following query, to find the free times:

```
SELECT free_from, free_until
FROM (SELECT a.end AS free_from,
             (SELECT MIN(c.start)
              FROM bookings c
              WHERE c.start>a.end
             ) as free_until
      FROM bookings a
      WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                        FROM bookings b
                        WHERE b.start BETWEEN a.end AND a.end + INTERVAL your_duration HOURS
                       ) AND
            a.end BETWEEN '10:00:00' AND '18:00:00'
     ) t
```

The output generated is:

```
free_from   free_until
14:30:00    15:00:00
16:00:00    NULL
```

Why is there a NULL in the end? Please help me solve this problem. Expected output should be:

```
free_from   free_until
10:00:00    13:00:00
14:30:00    15:00:00
16:00:00    18:00:00
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: added expected output

Answer (score 1):

try this:

first create table and insert records

```
CREATE TABLE bookings (
      id int NOT NULL,
      start time NOT NULL,
      endtime time NOT NULL
    )

    INSERT INTO bookings VALUES(1, '13:00:00', '14:30:00');
    INSERT INTO bookings VALUES(2, '15:00:00', '16:00:00');
```

then run this select query

```
SELECT free_from, free_until
FROM (SELECT a.endtime AS free_from,
(SELECT MIN(c.start)
              FROM bookings c
              WHERE c.start>a.endtime
             ) as free_until
            FROM bookings a
      WHERE a.endtime BETWEEN '10:00:00' AND '18:00:00'
       ) t where free_until IS NOT NULL;
```

**Note:** I changed your column *end* to *endtime*

Comment: it still doesn't display the expected output. it only displays the first record now `14:30:00 15:00:00`

Answer (score 0):

The first row of your output corresponds to the following data set:

```
a:
1, '13:00:00', '14:30:00'
c:
1, '13:00:00', '14:30:00'
2, '15:00:00', '16:00:00'
```

for "free_until", c.start must be higher than a.end, which is satisfied for this data set.(for 2nd row of C)

The second row of your output corresponds to the following data set:

```
a:
2, '15:00:00', '16:00:00'
c:
1, '13:00:00', '14:30:00'
2, '15:00:00', '16:00:00'
```

for "free_until", c.start>a.end but as you can see, a.end is 16:00 here, and no c.start is higher than this.
that's why null

Modify a.end of the second row to 14:00 and you will not get null value. :D

modify the data in the table:

Delete everything from bookings, then

```
INSERT INTO `bookings` VALUES(1, '13:00:00', '14:30:00'); 
INSERT INTO `bookings` VALUES(2, '15:00:00', '14:00:00');
```

Comment: thank you. please can you tell me what change to make in the query?

Comment: how can the end time of a booking (14:00:00), be before the start time (15:00:00) ?